# I get weird top and bottom whitespace between svg in rems

Tags: html, css, svg

maybe its stupid question but still..

Maybe someone can explain me why i am getting weird whitespace between svg in div block when i am writing with rems.

P.S font-size in html must be 10vw;

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWqwXZ

```
a
```

Comment: Have you read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are treated the same as `<img>`. By default, they are `inline-block` and thus sit on the baseline of the text.

If you don't want that, then just set the `<svg>` to `display:block`.

```css
html{
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg{
  wdith: 0.30rem;
  height: 0.30rem;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
    <path d="M429.9 758.48C425.78 751.33 416.63 748.88 409.47999999999996 753.01C402.33 757.13 399.87999999999994 766.28 404.00999999999993 773.43C408.12999999999994 780.5799999999999 417.2799999999999 783.03 424.42999999999995 778.9C431.5799999999999 774.77 434.03999999999996 765.63 429.9 758.48ZM422.94 776.31C417.21999999999997 779.6199999999999 409.9 777.66 406.6 771.9399999999999C403.29 766.2199999999999 405.25 758.9 410.97 755.5999999999999C416.70000000000005 752.29 424.01000000000005 754.2499999999999 427.32000000000005 759.9699999999999C430.62000000000006 765.6999999999999 428.66 773.0099999999999 422.94000000000005 776.31ZM422.34 766.85L414.57 771.33C413.84999999999997 771.75 413.27 771.4100000000001 413.26 770.59L413.21999999999997 761.52C413.21999999999997 760.6999999999999 413.79999999999995 760.36 414.51 760.78L422.34 765.35C423.04999999999995 765.76 423.04999999999995 766.44 422.34 766.85Z " fill-opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-402,-751)"></path>
</svg></div>
```